# Modifying rules for a given EC2 security group with Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I have recently been working on programatically adding and removing ingress rules to security groups on my EC2 server. However, I now seem to have hit a bit of a wall.

I would like to be able to modify existing rules through a python script, but I haven't been able to find any guidance on the Boto3 docs.

Is there any way in which this can be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [Boto3:SecurityGroup](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#securitygroup)

There is no API to modify a rule in SG. You have to revoke the rule first and then add the rule with the modified parameters using authorize. The link also has code snippets.

- authorize_egress()
- authorize_ingress()
- revoke_egress()
- revoke_ingress()

Comment: Yes, I've seen that method before, but I wondered if there was a cleaner way of modifying each rule. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: AWS is like the weather, if you don't like it, wait a minute. This list of options was true in 2016, but @Randhir-Kumar is correct as of 2021. modify_security_group_rules  is super helpful as you can now update instead of delete and create.

Answer (score 10):

AWS has added new API(*modify_security_group_rules*) wherein security group rule can be modified. Below code for reference:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('ec2')
sg_rules_list = [{'SecurityGroupRuleId': 'sgr-07de36a0521f39c8b',
                  'SecurityGroupRule': {
                      'IpProtocol': 'tcp',
                      'FromPort': 22,
                      'ToPort': 22,
                      'CidrIpv4': '3.3.3.3/32',
                      'Description': 'added ssh port'
                  }
                  }
                 ]
response = client.modify_security_group_rules(GroupId='sg-00f3b9232325b20fb',
                                              SecurityGroupRules=sg_rules_list)
```

More details on this on AWS blog: [Easily Manage Security Group Rules with the New Security Group Rule ID](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/easily-manage-security-group-rules-with-the-new-security-group-rule-id/)

Answer (score 8):

Seems like there are no way to modify security group rule. You have to delete the old one:

```
security_group.revoke_ingress(IpProtocol="tcp", CidrIp="0.0.0.0/0", FromPort=3306, ToPort=3306)
```

and add the new one:

```
security_group.authorize_ingress(IpProtocol="tcp",CidrIp="0.0.0.0/0",FromPort=3306,ToPort=3306)
```

Hope it help.