# how to use boto3 authorize_security_group_ingress to add a rule between two security groups in non default VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, aws-cli

I am trying to use boto3 to update security group rules, to add a rule to security group a (sg_a) to allow security group b (sg_b) to access port 8443.

I am trying to use EC2 client to achieve this with the following

```
ec2.authorize_security_group_ingress(
        GroupId=sg_a,
        SourceSecurityGroupName=sg_b,
        IpProtocol='tcp',
        FromPort=service_port,
        ToPort=service_port
    )
```

but I got this error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (VPCIdNotSpecified) when calling the AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress operation: No default VPC for this user.
```

How do I use authorize_security_group_igress for a non-default VPC?

Comment: [the docs may help](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.authorize_security_group_ingress)

Comment: the correct syntax is:
`
ec2.authorize_security_group_ingress(
        GroupId=sg_a,
        IpPermissions=[{
            'IpProtocol': 'tcp',
            'FromPort': from_port,
            'ToPort': to_port,
            'UserIdGroupPairs': [{
                'GroupId': sg_b
            }]
        }],
    )
`

Comment: Please write your solution and mark it as solved.

Answer (score 12):

the correct syntax is:

```
ec2.authorize_security_group_ingress( 
    GroupId=sg_a, 
    IpPermissions=[
        {'IpProtocol': 'tcp', 
        'FromPort': from_port, 
        'ToPort': to_port, 
        'UserIdGroupPairs': [{ 'GroupId': sg_b }] }
    ],
)
```

Comment: There may also be a way to modify it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69128078/453673