# How do we update aws security groups rules using Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

Does anyone know how to update the AWS security group rules using python boto3?

We have a security group called office_sg in all my accounts, and I need to update one of the rules with new descriptions for example.

the script is below;

```
import datetime
import boto3
import json
import itertools

AWS_Region='me-south-1'

session = boto3.Session(region_name=AWS_Region, profile_name='xxxxx')
org_client = session.client('organizations')
sts_client = session.client('sts')

awsaccount_list = [['123456465561', 'dev'], ['093556464361', 'staging']]

for aws_account in awsaccount_list:
    awsaccount = sts_client.assume_role(
        RoleArn=f'arn:aws:iam::{aws_account[0]}:role/SwitchRole',
        RoleSessionName='awsaccount_session'
    )

    ACCESS_KEY = awsaccount['Credentials']['AccessKeyId']
    SECRET_KEY = awsaccount['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey']
    SESSION_TOKEN = awsaccount['Credentials']['SessionToken']

    ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2', aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY, aws_session_token=SESSION_TOKEN, region_name=AWS_Region)
    describe_sg = ec2_client.describe_security_groups(
        Filters=[
            {
                'Name': 'group-name',
                'Values': [
                    '*office_sg*',
                ]
            },
        ],
    )

    for sg_res in describe_sg['SecurityGroups']:
        gpname = sg_res.get('GroupName')
        gpid = sg_res.get('GroupId')


        raw = [
            aws_account[1],
            gpname
        ]
        print(raw)

    sg_add_ing = ec2_client.authorize_security_group_ingress(
        GroupId=gpid,
        IpPermissions=[
            {
                'FromPort': 0,
                'IpProtocol': '-1',
                'IpRanges': [
                    {
                        'CidrIp': '10.2.3.4/32',
                        'Description': 'Sec'
                    },
                    {
                        'CidrIp': '10.5.6.7/32',
                        'Description': 'Sec'
                    },
                ],
                'ToPort': 0,
            },
            
    print(sg_add_ing)
```

Here am getting an expected error;

```
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidPermission.Duplicate) when calling the AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress operation: the specified rule "peer: 10.1.8.12/32, ALL, ALLOW" already exists
```

So can we use something called #overwrite or any other key to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no API for modifying sg rules. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/34595050/12259756 for a more elaborate answer on how to deal with this. Hope this helps you further!

Comment: There might be a new way to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69128078/453673